# Where should I put code with bindings slots to signals?

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt4

I'm writing a Python application with using if PyQt4 on Windows 7. I'm using QtDesigner to build my GUI. Every time when I'm adding new widgets I have to re-write bindings to signals because pyuic4 utility rewrites file every time. I've created test application to solve this problem:

**window.py** (Generated by pyui4.bat):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'window.ui'
#
# Created: Sun May 11 16:11:01 2014
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.10.4
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(439, 56)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lineEdit"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("pushButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText(_fromUtf8(""))
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton", None))
```

**app.py:** (My bindings)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from window import Ui_MainWindow
from window import _fromUtf8
import sys

def pushButtonClicked():
    global ui
    ui.label.setText(ui.lineEdit.text())


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)


QtCore.QObject.connect(ui.pushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("clicked()")), pushButtonClicked)
```

**run.py:** (runs the program)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from app import app, MainWindow

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is there a better way to save bindings between GUI generations?